Is there any way to can deal with missing data without imputation ? model considering NA values
My question is how to model data with NA values and without imputing. Is there any possibility? and what is the advantage and disadvantage? The problem is classification.

Please add more detail about your specific problem.

Flexible Imputation of Missing Data by Stef van Buuren explains the problems with many alternate methods in some detail. As Frank Harrell says in a comment on an answer below, a fully Bayesian model could be a good solution.

One way is to use classification trees and have "NA" as a separate value. This works better if the variables that are sometimes missing are categorical rather than numeric.
In a regression context, you can use mean or median imputation but a) I'm not sure this meets your requirement and b) It has problems, especially that it underestimates the noisiness of the model.

These methods are problematic.  I’ve laid out problems with alternatives to imputation here.  But the very best method of analyzing incomplete data is to use full Bayesian modeling without imputation.  This is what multiple imputation tries to approximate.
